# I want to update the Value of a row if it already exist in table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, ms-access

I want to update the value of Qty if the product name is already in the table.

```
            {
                connection.Open();

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "insert into Product ([Name],[Category],[Supplier],[Brand],[HSNCode],[SKUCode],[CP],[SP],[Psize],[Colour],[ProductImage],[BarcodeImage],[InsertionDate],[QTY]) values ('" + txtProduct.Text + "', '" + comboBoxCategory.Text + "', '" + comboBoxSupplier.Text + "', '" + txtBrand.Text + "', '"+txtHSN.Text+"','"+txtSKU.Text+"','"+txtCP.Text+"','"+txtSP.Text+"','"+comboBoxSize.Text+"','"+checkedListBoxColour.Text+"','"+ProductPictureBox.Image+"','"+BarcodePictureBox.Image+"', '"+ DateTime.Now.Date+ "','"+QtyTextBox.Text+ "')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [QTY] = VALUES(QTY+1);";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully");
                MessageBox.Show(txtProduct.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
```

I tried this query but it gives error missing semicolon.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MySQL? The square brackets around the column names suggest SQL Server (or maybe SQLite).

Comment: Please parameterize your queries...

Comment: @GMB I'm using ms access database

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919138/2144390) shows the general approach for Access (which does not support ON DUPLICATE KEY). The answer is for Python, but it should not be too difficult to translate it into C# code.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb after parameterizing same error.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a MYSQL extension to the `INSERT` statement that, if it finds a duplicate unique or primary key, will instead perform an `UPDATE`.

Check your table structure to see if that table has any unique or primary key.

Comment: Product name is a primary key